# Fedora network configuration

Tags: networking, fedora, resolv.conf

I've got a Fedora 31 instance configured with an IPv6 stack and that has join an IPA domain.

I've activated the IPv6 stack by editing `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

Added

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=primary_ipv6_address/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=ipv6_gateway
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
DNS1=IPv6 dns 1
DNS2=IPv6 dns 2
DNS3=IPv4 dns 1
DNS4=IPv4 dns 2
```

It all works well, but judging by the resulting `/etc/resolv.conf` DNS4 is not taken into account and no trace of a DNS search domain.

How can I mkae sure IPv4 stack has got 2 DNS configured as well as IPv6 if  only 3 DNS servers are supported?

The domain is taken into account in DNS searches (I can ping hosts by simple hostname) but it doesn't show in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Where is it configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glibc is [limited to 3 nameservers](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html). (It would not be a good user experience to wait for that many timeouts anyway.)

It is possible to send v4 addresses in v6 DNS, and vice versa. Confirm that each of your DNS servers can return AAAA and A records.

Any of the 4 should be able to serve all of your zones. So pick 3, perhaps 2 v6 and 1 v4.